# No such table sqlite when execute query on xamarin forms pcl

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have a problem with the reading of the tables on the SQLite database.

my OBJ_User class:

```
    namespace Fimap.Models
{
    public class OBJ_User
    {
        public int DLR_Id { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Username { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Password_Hash { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Nome { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Cognome { get; set; }
        public int DLR_Tipo { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Azienda { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Telefono { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Email { get; set; }
        public int DLR_Abilitato { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Time_Zone { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Country { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Culture { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Email1 { get; set; }
        public object DLR_MCC_Modello_Alias { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Anagrafica { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Firma { get; set; }
        public bool IsFIMAP { get; set; }
        public bool IsSTANDARD { get; set; }
        public bool IsDealerOrFimap { get; set; } //true dealer - false user
        public object DLR_Tipo_Esteso { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Abilitato_Esteso { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my interface in pcl project:

```
public interface IDatabaseConnection
    {
        SQLite.SQLiteConnection DbConnection();
    }
```

Android

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DatabaseConnection_Android))]
namespace Fimap.Droid
{
    public class DatabaseConnection_Android : IDatabaseConnection
    {
        public SQLiteConnection DbConnection()
        {
            var dbName = "FimapDB.db3";
            var path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), dbName);
            return new SQLiteConnection(path);
        }
    }
}
```

iOS

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DatabaseConnection_iOS))]
namespace App.iOS
{
    public class DatabaseConnection_iOS : IDatabaseConnection
    {
        public SQLiteConnection DbConnection()
        {
            var dbName = "FimapDB.db3";
            string personalFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string libraryFolder = Path.Combine(personalFolder);
            var path = Path.Combine(libraryFolder, dbName);
            return new SQLiteConnection(path);
        }
    }
}
```

pcl connection (database is right connect):

```
database = DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>().DbConnection();
```

[image]

query:

```
var test = database.Query<OBJ_User>("SELECT * FROM OBJ_User");
```

when i launch the query i have this error:

> SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: OBJ_User

[image]

OBJ_User is in the dabatase with one record.
Why the connection don't mapping the table ?
database variable is right connect to database sqlite, i don't understand because database don't get mapping from sqlite file.
Solution ?

if you want other info write me in the comment, i will answer

Comment: Do you call `database.CreateTable<OBJ_User>();` anywhere in your code? I know that you already have the table in the database, but you may need to "Create" it for the SQLite library to get the mapping.

Comment: Also as a side note, parameterizing your query can be helpful to avoid making spelling mistakes (ie
`var test = database.Query<OBJ_User>("SELECT * FROM ?", nameof(OBJ_user));`
The ? just gets filled in with the parameter and the library does some work internally to make sure it's formatted correctly.

Comment: if i do database.CreateTable<OBJ_User>(); i get this error: System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Object, then if i do var test = database.Query<OBJ_User>("SELECT * FROM ?", nameof(OBJ_user)); i have the error on OBJ_User.

Comment: Can you add the code for your OBJ_User class declaration? I think this has something to do with having a List of non CLR type in your class declaration which is not supported by the library. [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2546/create-table-in-xamarin-throws-exception-because-of-generic-list)

Comment: i added the class, do you think that is wrong class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQLite library doesn't know how to map the properties of type object to a sqlite column. The SQLite library supports the following column types by default: string, int, double, byte[], DateTime.

Comment: i have tried to remove element with type "object", i have left only string and int object..that works.! Thanks. I sign right answer.

Comment: The last question, if we do not do "database.CreateTable <OBJ_User> ();" the table is not created, you can use an existing database? since I have one with about 1000 records.

Comment: The problem remains, does the mapping, while if I table creation works, but I'm going to lose existing records if I create a table.

Comment: CreateTable will not drop any records that you have in your database. It simply creates a table if it does not exist and adds that mapping to the connection. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: exatly i have tried after your response, thank you so much. good works