# Which package should be used in Xamarin Forms instead of Android.Content to get class Intent?

Tags: c#, android-intent, xamarin.forms

## TL;DR:

Need to use class `Intent` for different things. Found examples online where `using Android.Content` is used. This doesn't apply to **Xamarin.Forms** (I think). What **NuGet** package is needed for it to work?

## Nah.. I got time:

### Intro (unnecessary read)

*I'm starting out with mobile app development so I'm pretty much clueless about anything. Hoping to get a concise answer here.*

My app is primarily `WebView` container with some other minor functionalities. I'm using **Visual Studio 2019** and **Xamarin.Forms**, but at the moment I am compiling to **Android** alone. **iOS** and **UWP** are my goal once, at least one app is fully finished for **Android**.

### Problem 1 and where I am

Now I need to add two things. One is "*Rate us*" and the other is "*Share*" link, both in the main menu (swipe from left or click the hamburger icon to open it). I already have three list items in the menu, where each of them open a page in the app.

I figured out how to add another item to the menu, but I currently link this list item to `market://details?id=com.mycompany.myapp` url of my app on **PlayStore**. It opens nicely in **PlayStore**, but after pressing the back button it goes to home screen instead of back to the app.

### Current code where I added "Rate Us"

#### MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using MyApp.Models;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.Views {
    ...
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage {
        ...
        public async Task NavigateFromMenu(int id) {
            if (!MenuPages.ContainsKey(id) {
                switch(id) {
                    ...
                    case (int)MenuItemType.RateUs:
                        await Browser.OpenAsync("market://details?id=com.mycompany.myapp", BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
                        // startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.mycompany.myapp")));
                        break;
                    ...
                }
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

#### MenuPage.xaml.cs

```
using MyApp.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.Views {
    ...
    public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage {
        ...
        public MenuPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem> {
                ...
                new HomeMenuItem { id = MenuItemType.RateUs, Title="Rate Us", Icon="\uf005" },
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### HomeMenuItem.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Models {
    public enum MenuItemType {
        ...
        RateUs,
        ...
    }
    public class HomeMenuItem {
        public MenuItemType Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### What I tried

As you can see in `//` comment in MainPage.xaml.cs I found a different solution, that would perhaps return me back to my app after going back from **PlayStore**.

This particular solution is (obviously???) problematic at `startActivity`, tooltip stating

> The name 'startActivity' does not exist in the current context

but there are other much more complex solution like [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720632/9583480) that have `startActivity` wrapped in `public void function()` which - I guess - helps.

### Problem 2

I need to add another List Item to side menu titled "*Share*" where the device will ask which app do you want to share with (or copy to clipboard) and then use that app to share some text and a link of my choosing (same for all users). Again, any [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941093/how-to-share-entire-android-app-with-share-intent) I find uses `Intent`.

At a complete loss here. If you can't give me the tools and a manual how to use them, at least point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to call the Intent class in your App, one of them, and maybe the best would be by making use of [`DependencyService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

From the docu:

> The DependencyService class is a service locator that enables Xamarin.Forms applications to invoke native platform functionality from shared code.

### Small Example for your use case

As you can see from the docu, the first you have to do is to create an **Interface** to define the method you want to implement. In our case, i will create a simple interface that defines a single method called `LaunchAppInPlayStore` (this you can call whatever you want!):

```cs
namespace App2
{
    public interface Interface1
    {
        void LaunchAppOnPlayStore();
    }
}
```

Lets go on and implement this in the **Android** project: for this purpose i add a class called `MyInterfaceImplementationAndroid` in it and make inherit from `Interface1`. Then i implement the method from the **Interface** as follows:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Content;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(App2.Droid.MyInterfaceImplementationAndroid))]

namespace App2.Droid
{
    class MyInterfaceImplementationAndroid : Interface1
    {
        public void LaunchAppOnPlayStore()
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("market://details?id=com.mycompany.myapp")));
        }
    }
}
```

You should note that in my example i use the `Context` provided by *CurrentActivity* plugin by @JamesMontemagno (this is just circumstantial, and in my own apps i myself use a different approach as i described in [another SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801549/where-to-put-and-how-to-read-from-manually-created-db-file-using-xamarin-forms/58810278#58810278) (See the part where i add the `MainApplication` class to get the Current `Context`, or see the [blog post](https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/11/xamarinforms-25-and-local-context-on.html) by @DavidBritch (worth to read!)))

We are almost done! Now you just have to call the method in your shared code as follows:
For the sake of this example i created a simple page with a button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App2.TestInyection">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Go to shop!"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and in the code behind i just call the `LaunchAppOnPlayStore` method as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App2
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestInyection : ContentPage
    {
        public TestInyection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<Interface1>().LaunchAppOnPlayStore();
        }
    }
}
```